# Android UX flow, next button on ActionBar

Tags: java, android, ios

I am in a UX flow conundrum. In the ActionBar http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html, I am tasked to place a 'Next' button similar to that in [iOS](http://www.webholism.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/iphone-email-setup6.jpg).

I am aware that Android has no equivalent button for that, is there a suggestion?

Comment: If you are asking an Android question not everyone will be familiar with the "Next" button on iOS you are talking about. You should include an example of that and not so much of the ActionBar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it depends on your needs. Generally apps with a need for a Next button put it somewhere near the bottom-right of the screen.

I would personally be against putting it on the ActionBar as some devices handle it differently. Older devices might end up putting it behind the Menu button, and you'd have to be careful not to let it go into the overflow '...' menu as it may be too hidden-away in there (again, depending on your use case).

The other thing to remember is that putting it on the right of the Action Bar suggests that the button on the left of the Action Bar is a 'back' button, which is is not ([It's an 'up' button](https://developer.android.com/training/design-navigation/ancestral-temporal.html)).

I'm thinking more something like this: [image]